# Ecto model query to return related objects through a one to one mapping

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I'm having difficulty in trying to locate in the documentation on how to do the following Ecto query. I have a model `events` which has a one to one mapping to a `customer` through `event.customer_id`.

In an existing query pipeline, I am querying on `events` and return `events` which have a distinct customer only:

```
  defp events_by_distinct_customer(query) do
    query
    |> distinct([e], e.customer_id)
  end
```

What I need to do in addition to this, is to return the related customer objects instead of the events. How do I do this, and what is the method/description of what I'm asking to do?

Comment: You want only customer results ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a simple `inner join` to the customer's tables.

```
query
|> distinct([e], e.customer_id)
|> join(:inner, [e], c in Customers, on: e.customer_id == c.id)
|> select([e, c], c)
```

An inner join only returns rows that have both sides of the join, then using `select/3` you can extract from the result set only the customer.